# Pandas: how to create new columns based on more than one condition?

Tags: pandas, numpy, where-clause

Hi everybody and thanks for your time!

This is my df

```
Population  GDP Surface Area    HDI Continent
0   35.467  1785387 9984670 0.913   America
1   63.951  2833687 640679  0.888   Europe
2   80.940  3874437 357114  0.916   Europe
3   60.665  2167744 301336  0.873   Europe
4   127.061 4602367 377930  0.891   Asia
5   64.511  2950039 242495  0.907   Europe
6   318.523 17348075    9525067 0.915   America
```

Why when I use this code (one condition) everything works...

```
df['value_new'] = np.where((df["GDP"] > 3000000 < 1000000), 1, 0)
print(df)
```

But when I use two conditions, it doesn't work anymore?

```
df['value_new'] = np.where((df["GDP"] > 3000000 & df["Surface Area"] < 1000000), 1, 0)
print(df)
```

Error is

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Also: any other suggestion to do this kind of operation in a more efficient way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are close, need `()` around masks because priority of operation:

```
df['value_new'] = np.where((df["GDP"] > 3000000) & (df["Surface Area"] < 1000000), 1, 0)
```